# ModuleNotFoundError for several packages after importing in editable mode

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am working on a statistical package, lets call it "statistics" in python and have to add some functions and classes on the go. For convenience I want to work in editable mode on the package, since I dont want to reinstall the package after each change. Note, I used the package before and installing and using it in normal mode works perfectly.

I spun up a virtualenv with Python3.6, copied the package into the virtual environment folder to only fiddle around on that locally. I installed the package by cd'ing into the packages folder where the setup.py is and

```
pip install -e .
```

I made sure that the packages topfolder has the same name as the package itself, since I read thats a source of errors.

Now the phenomenon happening is that I get a "ModuleNotFoundError" for some modules, which are however definitely installed regarding to "pip freeze" and "pip list".

It seems rather random, which ones are working. E.g. I can import numpy and cycler, but eofs and xarray don't work.

Does anyody have an idea of where to look for errors?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Show the project directory structure and the `setup.py` file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually I solved the problem. I was creating the environment using just

```
virtualenv -p3.6
```

but the standard python interpreter was python2.7. There seemed to be some conflict with that, because when using

```
python3 venv -p3.6
```

all my troubles where gone and editable mode works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Did you:

```
pip3 install <package>
```

first? That is the most common reason. If you have a lot of packages you want to install, create a file called "requirements.txt", type all the packages in the file and do the following:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

This should solve all your problems. If you have a self-made package you are using, change into the directory of where the setup.py for that package is and run the following:

```
pip3 install .
```

Comment: When I run the setup.py from my custom package, the other dependent packages are downloaded automatically. I checked and they are in the lib/python3.6/site-packages folder and being listed if I look them up via "pip freeze" as I said. Still I can not import them

Comment: Actually I solved the problem. I was creating the environment using just "virtualenv -p3.6", but the standard python interpreter was python2.7. When using "python3 venv -p3.6" all my troubles where gone and editable mode works like a charm